# Delete first element after if statement

Tags: php, smarty

Need to delete first element after all this statements, i try to add `key=i` to second `foreach`, and add `{if $i!=0}`, but it dont work for me, because i have multilevel system and after all `if` statements first `$i` is different for all pages.

```
{foreach from=$page.path item=e}
  {assign var=element value=0}
    {foreach from=$menu3 item=r}
     {if $e.page_id==$r.page_id}{assign var=element value=$r}{/if}
      {if $element._left < $r._left && $element._right > $r._right}
       {if $r._level==$element._level+1 && $r._level==$page._level}
         <a href="{$r.url}">{$r.name}</a>
       {/if}
      {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: i solve it with another if else statement

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to you foreach and do something like this to get index

```
{foreach from=$items key=myId item=i name=foo}
    {$smarty.foreach.foo.index} <!-- It will show index -->
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I already try add index and show it, and for different pages first index is different.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to display first element in each of the menus you have, right?

```
{foreach from=$page.path item=e}
    {assign var=first_skipped value=0}
    {assign var=element value=0}
    {foreach from=$menu3 item=r}
        {if !$first_skipped}
            {assign var=first_skipped value=1}
        {else}
            {if $e.page_id==$r.page_id}{assign var=element value=$r}{/if}
            {if $element._left < $r._left && $element._right > $r._right}
                {if $r._level==$element._level+1 && $r._level==$page._level}
                <a href="{$r.url}">{$r.name}</a>
                {/if}
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: what is first_skipped ?

Comment: Its a variable which acts as a flag. It is set to 0 for each page and updated to 1 after first element in each menu.

Comment: don't understand how to use this =(

Comment: See updated code. Is it more clear now? Just use another variable to track whether or nor first element was skipped. If that's what you need